# absolute position hard right aligned with a left margin

Tags: css, xhtml, positioning, margin, css-position

I can't work out how to stop an absolutely positioned element at a particular point.

On [this page](http://www.webthread.com.au) you will see the words "Get me on your team" these words and the robot are absolutely positioned so they are always hard right on the screen. What I am trying to do is when the screen is re-sized to become more narrow I want to stop it overlapping the mac image. I have tried adding margin-left: 900px; but it has no effect when making the screen smaller. Does anybody know how to stop the words and robot at a particular point when making the browser more narrow?

Comment: Stop them in what sense? So that they disappear offscreen to the right?

Comment: Yeh that's right Robusto... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to set a `min-width` on the containing element.

```
body {
  min-width: 1024px;
  position: relative;
}
```

also set position relative so that the robot is positioned absolute to the body in stead of to the window.

Comment: Thanks Jan, I had set it to relative but had set min-width to the wrong width, it makes sense just requires a bit more brain power. Thanks again ;)

Comment: No problem, when I looked it wasn't there so I added it. +1 for the question. This is one I've struggled with myself in an earlier project.

Comment: Thanks Jan, the scroll bar appearing when the robot begins to slide out of view is perfect so hidden will stop people from scrolling to see him. Unless I trigger scrolls with another element. I haven't tested ie yet so it may be needed.

Comment: Its not needed, now that I think about it, it is not a good idea for people with a small screen. I will remove that from my answer.